# How to block events to the underlying scene but not the window when a Dialog is open?

Tags: javafx, dialog, modal-dialog, javafx-8

Basically, I have an application that opens mostly modal dialogs as I dont want the user to be able to continue working in the main app while a dialog is open. However, `Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL` as well as `Modality.WINDOW_MODAL` both also prevent minimizing and maximizing windows. That is a problem when a dialog gets triggered by an non-user event and the user has minimized the window already -> he cant open it again.

Now I have a sort of workaround that opens the dialog manually on the main Screen of the user. I could also simply make the dialog non-modal if the app is minimized, but then he could work in the application while ignoring the dialog. Both solutions are not particularly pretty and not exactly what I want.

I know its a "feature" but is there really no way to interact with the window but not the scene of the owner Stage? Perhaps a way to block user events to the scene without using modality? Would seem like a pretty common use case to me.

Here is a minimalistic code example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class DialogDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Stage mainStage = new Stage();
        Button showDialogBtn = new Button("show Dialog");
        showDialogBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Dialog<ButtonType> dialog = new Dialog<ButtonType>();
                dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
                dialog.initOwner(mainStage);
                //prevents mainStage from being resized, mini-/maximized and closed
                dialog.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
                dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CLOSE);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
        ScrollPane pane = new ScrollPane(showDialogBtn);
        pane.setMinSize(600, 480);
        mainStage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        mainStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post a small example?

Comment: added a small example, tough its really the case with any modal dialogue that has an owner.